# Git push heroku master: connection aborted

Tags: git, heroku

I downloaded the heroku toolbet but, when I try to upload my files to the server with

```
git push heroku master
```

After 4-5 minutes get this error:

```
Read from socket failed: the connection was aborted
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I've already tried to generate a new ssh key and to upload it but it doesn't fix the problem.

Can you help me please?

Comment: are you logged in to heroku, if you run `heroku login` from terminal

Comment: Yes, sure, I'm logged in.

Comment: @rajasimon they say in the question they have tried that already. Did you create the app on Heroku or someone else? Are you owner/collaborator of the app?

Comment: I am the owner, the only one user who has access to it. I have 2 heroku accounts: it doesn't work with any account. Is it a problem of my PC?